# Estimate marginal effect in triple interaction

Tags: r, prediction, effects, interaction, marginal-effects

I have a model with a triple interaction, similar to this:

```
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ am*cyl*hp, mtcars)
```

I am trying to show how the effect of `am` changes based on the conditions of `cyl` and `hp`. Using the `Effect()` function from the `effects` library, I can show the predicted values of `mpg`. This works well and fairly quickly with my dataset. However, I want to show the size of the gap between the points in each case.

```
library(effects)
p1 <- as.data.frame(Effect(m1, focal.predictors = c("am", "cyl", "hp"), xlevels = list(am=c(0, 1), cyl=c(4,8), hp = c(100, 200))))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(p1, aes(cyl, fit, color = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width = 0, position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  facet_grid(~hp)
```

[image]

I have tried using the `margins()` function from the `margins` library. As shown below. This shows the average marginal effect (AME), which I suppose is what I am trying to show. However, it takes an exorbitant amount of time with my dataset because I control for country fixed effects interacted with year and one of the independent variables.

```
p2 <- margins(m1, at=list(cyl = c(4, 8), hp = c(100, 200)), variables = "am")
p2 <- summary(p2)

ggplot(p2, aes(cyl, AME, color = as.factor(hp))) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width = 0, position = position_dodge(0.5))
```

[image]

Is there a way I can use `Effect()` to show the estimated gap between predicted values?

Comment: When you say, "I want to show the size of the gap between the points in each case.", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong I want to show the estimated marginal effect of `am` (i.e., the difference between the circles and the triangles in the first graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the relevant information to make the plot you want is in the output from the `Effect()` function.  First, let's run the model and generate the effect object.

```r
library(effects)
#> Loading required package: carData
#> lattice theme set by effectsTheme()
#> See ?effectsTheme for details.
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

m1 <- lm(mpg ~ am*cyl*hp + wt + drat, mtcars)
E <- Effect(m1, 
            focal.predictors = c("am", "cyl", "hp"), 
            xlevels = list(am=c(0, 1), 
                           cyl=c(4,8), 
                           hp = seq(52, 335, length=10)))
p1 <- as.data.frame(E)
```

Now, to get the difference between `am == 0` and `am == 1`, we'll need to identify those values in the data frame `p1`.

```r
w0 <- which(p1$am == 0)
w1 <- which(p1$am == 1)
```

We can then make a matrix that we will use to generate the differences in effects.  We initialize it to have all zero values and it needs to have `nrow(p1)` rows and `length(w0)` columns:

```r
D <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(p1), ncol = length(w0))
```

Now, each column corresponds to a difference between the `am == 0` and `am == 1` prediction for a particular value of `hp` and `cal`.  For the values where `am == 0`, we need the matrix to have -1 values and for `am == 1`, we need it to have values of 1.  We can accomplish this as follows:

```r
D[cbind(w0, 1:ncol(D))] <- -1
D[cbind(w1, 1:ncol(D))] <- 1
```

We can then get the differences this way:

```r
diffs <- c(t(p1$fit) %*% D)
```

Just to make sure we got the right numbers, let's look at the first two values of `diffs`:

```r
diffs[1:2]
#> [1]  3.2716241 -0.8526864
p1[1:4, ]
#>   am cyl hp      fit       se     lower    upper
#> 1  0   4 52 24.74134 2.784239 18.967181 30.51550
#> 2  1   4 52 28.01296 2.203560 23.443061 32.58287
#> 3  0   8 52 19.12017 3.466758 11.930556 26.30979
#> 4  1   8 52 18.26749 4.455793  9.026738 27.50823
p1$fit[2]-p1$fit[1]
#> [1] 3.271624
p1$fit[4]-p1$fit[3]
#> [1] -0.8526864
```

You can see that the first two values of `diffs` are the same as the ones we would calculate from `p1`.  Now, we need to calculate the variance of the differences, we can do this as follows:

```r
v_diffs <- t(D) %*% vcov(E) %*% D
```

Next, we make a dataset that will allow us to plot these differences.  We keep the data where `am == 0` just so we don't have replicated rows for each comparison. Then, we add in the differences, standard errors and confidence bounds.

```r
p11 <- p1[p1$am == 0, ]
p11$diff <- diffs
p11$se_diff <- sqrt(diag(v_diffs))
p11$lwr <- p11$diff - 1.96*p11$se_diff
p11$upr <- p11$diff + 1.96*p11$se_diff
```

Then, we can make the plot.  Now, each point represents the difference between `am==0` and `am==1` for each different value of `hp` and `cyl`:

```r
ggplot(p11, aes(x=hp, y=diff, ymin=lwr, ymax=upr)) + 
  geom_pointrange() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype=2, col="red") + 
  facet_wrap(~as.factor(cyl)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using [the `marginaleffects` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/), which was designed as a “successor” to `margins`, with more flexibility, more supported model types, and is often *much* faster. (Disclaimer: I am the author.)

```r
library(marginaleffects)

m <- lm(mpg ~ am*cyl*hp, mtcars)

plot_cme(m, effect = "am", condition = c("hp", "cyl"))
```

[image]

Customize the plot with `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot_cme(m, effect = "am", condition = c("hp", "cyl"), draw = FALSE) |>
    ggplot(aes(condition1, dydx, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
    geom_ribbon(alpha = .2) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~condition2) +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

Just the numeric results:

```r
mfx <- marginaleffects(m)
summary(mfx, by = "cyl")
#> Average marginal effects 
#>   Term cyl   Effect Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    2.5 %    97.5 %
#> 1   am   6  2.00971    1.95284  1.0291 0.3034237 -1.81779  5.837211
#> 2   am   4  5.08709    1.76482  2.8825 0.0039453  1.62811  8.546073
#> 3   am   8  2.15232    2.23291  0.9639 0.3350919 -2.22410  6.528733
#> 4  cyl   6 -0.94326    0.71546 -1.3184 0.1873742 -2.34554  0.459026
#> 5  cyl   4 -2.06503    0.85842 -2.4056 0.0161455 -3.74751 -0.382553
#> 6  cyl   8  0.47177    1.71136  0.2757 0.7828002 -2.88243  3.825974
#> 7   hp   6 -0.05691    0.02592 -2.1956 0.0281202 -0.10772 -0.006108
#> 8   hp   4 -0.09174    0.03417 -2.6852 0.0072497 -0.15870 -0.024776
#> 9   hp   8 -0.03583    0.01893 -1.8930 0.0583573 -0.07293  0.001267
#> 
#> Model type:  lm 
#> Prediction type:  response
```